# Getting all 0's from postgres database for Guid value

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core

I am doing a simple GET and POST request in .net core using LINQ.
Both operations are working fine, I am auto-generating GUID in the Postgres database and it is working as expected, 
but during the GET request, the GUID I am getting is all 0's.

```
Model Class - 

public class Model {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid UUID { get; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

I am using only `get;` for GUID because I am auto-generating it in the database. When I add `set;` or `private set;`, then the database function that generates the GUID doesn't work.
And my works fine for all the other data.

```
Insert query - 

DataModel.Model model = new DataModel.Model 
{
    Name = "abc",
    CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow
}

respository.Insert(model);
```

```
repository.Insert(model) - 

public async Task Insert(TEntity entity)
{
    var dbSet = dataContext.Set<TEntity>();
    if (dataContext == null || dbSet == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    dbSet.Add(entity);
    await dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

```
GET query - 

Model query = repository.Get(data => data.Id == 2).FirstOrDefault();


repository.Get() - 

public IQueryable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where = null, int take = 0, int skip = 0)
        {
            var DbSet = dataContext.Set<TEntity>();
            if (dataContext == null || DbSet == null)
            {
                return new List<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
            }

            IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet;
            if (where != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(where);
            }

            return take == 0 ? query : query.Skip(skip).Take(take);
        }
```

```
Mapping model class for json output - 

Dto.Model mapModel = new Dto.Model 
{
   [JsonPropertyName("id")]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   [JsonPropertyName("uuid")]
   public Guid UUID { get; set; }

   [JsonPropertyName("name")]
   public string Name { get; set; }

   [JsonPropertyName("created_at")]
   public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}

Mapping - 

mapModel.Id = model.Id;
mapModel.Name = model.Name;
mapModel.UUID = model.UUID;
mapModel.CreatedAt = model.CreatedAt;
```

It is generated in the database,
[image]

But, getting like this in postman,

[image]

Comment: Could you please to show an action where you have all 0

Comment: There's some context missing here. How is the table mapped? Are you using an ORM?

Comment: Guid is a value type which initializes as all zeros. Basically, it's not being set.

Comment: @Andy Yes, it is not being set from the code, but it is set in the database using a function. I can see it being added in the database, but when using the GET request, it is not giving the right result

Comment: @PaulSinnema I am using an EF as an ORM, but using a function to generate GUID in the database. Sorry I got confused for a sec.

Comment: There has to be some means you get the data from database table into your model. What is it?

Comment: @Sergey I have added the screenshots in the question.

Comment: @AshwinPandey: Show us the code where you read the table and add the data into your model please.

Comment: I still don't see you action that gets your model. And I see UUID NOT GUIDID

Comment: I have added more code in the question, please let me know if I need to add something else.

Comment: EF Core can not populate readonly properties with values generated in the database, add a setter or add private setter and configure EF Core to use private setter to set value when entity retrieved from the database.

Comment: @Fabio I have added the mapping part that I am doing after getting the data from database, there I am setting it for json, is it what you are talking about?

Comment: @Fabio You are right in the case of GET request, but when I add a setter then the database function that auto-generates the GUID doesn't work.

Comment: You need to configure EF Core to generate new value on "add" - For `Guid` you don't need to do it on database side `.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` - will generate new unique `Guid`. For database side you need to configure to use database function for new value.   [Value generated on add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=fluent-api#value-generated-on-add-1)

Comment: @Fabio This solved my problem, please add these points as an answer so that I can mark it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core can not populate readonly properties with values generated in the database.
You can add a setter which will be automatically mapped to the database column.
Or add private setter and configure EF Core to use private setter to set value when entity retrieved from the database.

You can configure EF Core to generate unique values for `Guid` type when you insert new record.

In MyDbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Model>()
        .Property(b => b.UUID)
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
}
```

In your specific case I would suggest to get rid of `Id` column, `UUID` column is also unique and can be made a primary key.

[Value generated on add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=fluent-api#value-generated-on-add)

Answer (score 0):

According the postman screen shot you have to change your model to:

```
public class Model {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UUID { get; set; }
}
```

And notice that I added  set to UUID. Without this Ef can't assign UUID a new value. It will have default value - all 0s.

Comment: UUID is the name to print in json, it is there as ```[JsonPropertyName("uuid")]```

Comment: I still don't see you get action. We can't help you without this.

Comment: Sorry , but now we still need repository.GET

Comment: Since you have 0s when you get your model  not when you insert the new record, we  don't need you repository.Insert , we need repository.Get

Comment: I have added it in the question, please let me know if it is what you need

Comment: I have updated the question again after @Fabio's comment, please let me know if you find anything., that'll be really helpful.

Comment: I still can't find something like this public async Task<Model> Get (int id). Could you please show it

Comment: And what means [NULL] at your screenshot